# Wordpress super admin login issue. (Automatically logout)

Tags: plugins, multisite

I have created super admin and after login the super admin in admin panel it's not allowed to access other pages like(plugins & users).

It's automatically logout again redirect to admin login page.

Please anyone let me know . Whats is the reason this type of issue accrue.

I have deactivate all plugins & themes and checked the issue still raised.

Comment: please try to rename your .htaccess  file

Comment: @vikrantzilpe Thanks for reply. But still this accrue

Comment: please check url: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-login-page-refreshing-and-redirecting-issue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue is might be the primary key in the database.

you have to set primary and index key in the wp_user and wp_usermeta table

do that and let me know if the issue is resolved or is still there

hope this will be help you and waiting for you response

Comment: Man you are awasome. We have facing the issue in last 3 days. Unbelievable .Thanks you so much.